# rewrite url with custom plugin with permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have developed plugin and uses shortcode to display.

So, there is two type of items to display like

if get title in url, display single item and if not all items so i have added into if else in condition.

So for that  title, i have passed

```
add_query_arg( array('title' =>sanitize_title($data->get_title())), get_permalink($post_id) );
```

now url is generated by this is domain.com/post-slug/?title=nameoftitle

but i want to url like domain.com/post-slug/nameoftitle

I have tried following code but not working

```
function update_rewrite_rules() {

    add_rewrite_tag( '%title%', '([^/]*)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
            $newVarRegex,
            'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&title=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
}
 add_action( 'init', 'update_rewrite_rules' );
```

but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution of it. working code is:

```
function js_update_rewrite_rules() {

    add_rewrite_tag( '%title%', '([^/]*)' );

    $rewrite_rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    $newVarRegex = '^([^/]*)/title/([^/]*)/?';

    // check if the rule exists
    if ( !isset( $rewrite_rules[$newVarRegex] ) ) {

        add_rewrite_rule(
            $newVarRegex,
            'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&title=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}

function js_on_activation() {

    js_update_rewrite_rules();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'js_on_activation' );


function js_on_init() {

    js_update_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'js_on_init' );
```